# Compute the probability distribution of the value of a portfolio

Tags: statistics

*The Long-Term Capital Depreciation Group owns a portfolio
that has \$20,000 in a fund holding US stocks, and $30,000 in a fund holding
European stocks. The annual return on the US fund is (approximately) normally
distributed with mean 10% and standard deviation 5%. The annual return on the
European fund is (approximately) normally distributed with mean 1% and
standard deviation 8%. The co-variance between the two funds’ annual returns is
0.002.

Compute the probability distribution of the value of the Long-Term Capital
Depreciation Group’s portfolio after one year.

What is the probability that the value of their portfolio at year end is less than
$50,000?*

I am not sure what I'm being asked for in question 1. I know the distributions of return are as follows: $X-N(2000, 1000^2), Y-N(300,2400^2)$ but how to go about computing distribution for the value of stocks?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=20,000(1+r_u)+30,000(1+r_e)$, where $r_u$ is the annual return on the US stocks, $r_e$ is that on the European stocks. Then $p$ is the portfolio value at the end of the year. Recall that sums of normal variables are normal, and the probability density function of a normal random variable is characterized by its mean and variance. You can compute the mean and variance of $p$ given the information you've stated, and then use the PDF of $p$ to answer the question.